# firebase firestore cannot simultaneously update field/column of TIMESTAMP data type and others field/column of String/Number Data type

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Firebase Firestore cannot simultaneously update field/column of  TIMESTAMP data type and other fields/columns of String/Number Data types. Tried for  four days it didn't work. I had to do that separately. Please has anyone else noticed this? I tried with JavaScript and Java/Android did't Work.

```
 WriteBatch batch = utilfb.getDatabaseFireStore().batch(); DocumentReference BioDataV2 = utilfb.getDatabaseFireStore().collection("OnlineUsers").document("sers1");  batch.update(BioDataV2, "Last_Seen", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());                                                                    batch.update(BioDataV2, "A_Status",1);   batch.update(BioDataV2, "A_Fcm_Id", seuna);
batch.commit()addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {                                                                                                             @Override                                                                                                              public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task){  if (task.isSuccessful()) { Log.d("TAG","Succsss");                                                                                                           } else{Log.d("TAG","Failed");                                                                                                                  }                                                                                                                                                                                                              }});
```

Comment: Why are you saying that cannot?

Comment: I mean you can't at the same time update a field of Timestamp Data Type and other(s) with different Data type.

Comment: I understood that. But why are you saying that? Do you have an error or what?

Comment: It failed when I tried do that even though it doesn't give you an error.

Comment: What does "it fails" mean? If the app crashes, please add the entire stacktrace from your logcat.

Comment: I mean the update is not committed to the database.

Comment: In this case, please edit your question by adding the entire code.